# Group TableView items from NSArray returned in JSON Response in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I have a table view and I want to populate the table view with the values provided to me in a `JSON` response in the form of `NSArray` and I have used the code below to extract this `NSArray`:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        print(json)
                        if let listDictionary = parseJSON["list"] as? NSArray {
                            print("LIST: \(listDictionary)")
                        }
})
```

In JSON response, I get the following array of two elements as shown below:

```
list = (
        {
        "is_cover" = 0;
        "is_recommand" = 0;
        name = "Helena's Signature Dish";
        ord = 5;
        price = "105.00";
        remark = "Helena's special made dish is one of the most priced and delicious dishes in the whole world.";
        thumb = "56c351887a0e0.jpg";
        },
        {
        "is_cover" = 0;
        "is_recommand" = 0;
        name = "Pineapple Fried Rice";
        ord = 6;
        price = "110.00";
        remark = "We have the most delicious pineapple rice in the whole world!";
        thumb = "56c704e15da79.jpg";
        }
);
```

Now I want to show the value "name", "price" and "remark" fields from each element in the array into a `UITableView`.

But I can't find a way to break the values for name, price and remark for each element and put them into an another array so they can be displayed in a table view somehow because each element contains a very long string and I only need to extract some values from this string. Can anyone please help me with this as I'm very new to Swift.

Thanks!

Comment: is it worked@laser2302

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by putting values in "name", "price" and "remark" fields into another array using flatMap as shown below:

```
let nameArray = listArray.flatMap({ element in (element["name"] as? String)! })
```

And then I got something like:

Name's: (
    "Helena's Special Dish",
    "Pineapple Fried Rice"
)

and then in the tableView function for cellForRowAtIndexPath I grouped the values in tableview.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make a second array, Only extarct particular json from array in `cellForRowatIndexPath` on dictinary by `objectatindex` method of array and now you can access.

Answer (score 0):

- You can achieve it by creating a model Class which contains only
  those properties which you needed.
- Once you get the response array from server , iterate though each
  dictionary and create a Model Object.Add this model objects in the
  Array.
- Use this model object in the Array for applying data in your cell using the index

> - One more thing to add is always prefer using objects as it gives (.)dot syntax & autosuggestion, so there will be less chances of
>     making mistakes. As if you use Dictionary there will be more chances
>     of using incorrect key getting crash

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to use model Class or model Objects as I'm very new to Swift. But I found another way by using flatMap. You can see the answer in the answers section below.